# how to add a row in a datagridview using textboxes and a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharp

So i have a datagridview which is populated with a list of objects.
I added on the form 3 textboxes and a button. The question is how to insert and populate another row into the datagridview with the text from textboxes.

this is my class:

```
class Professor
    {
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private double salary; 

    public Professor()
    {
        this.id= 0;
        this.name = null;
        this.salary= 0;
    }
    public Professor(int m, string n, double s)
    {
        this.id= m;
        this.name = n;
        this.salary= s;
    }
    }
```

This is the declaration for the list:

```
ArrayList listProfessors = new ArrayList();
```

This is the button which populates the DataGridView:

```
private void addInGridViewFromList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string linie;
            System.IO.StreamReader file= new System.IO.StreamReader("D:\\Profesor\\Profesor\\Profesori.txt");
        while ((line= file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] t = line.Split(',');                
        listProfessors .Add(new Professor(Convert.ToInt32(t[0]), t[1], Convert.ToDouble(t[2])));
        }
        file.Close();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = listProfessors ;
    }
```

And here on this button i want to add another row manually(using texboxes) into the DataGridView.

```
private void AddFromKeyboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a button event that do what you want, and when the button pressed you add a new row with the textboxes you want.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
    }
```

edit: So try to add a new item to your list from the button:

```
private void AddFromKeyboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   listProfessors.Add(new Professor(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text, Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before anything you should provide us a little bit of your code where you are doing some stuffs, but without it also I will try to explain it to you,

first of all what you might do is next: check is your datagrid's source some list, so you might create an corresponding object from a your textbox and you might simply add it to your list which is source to datagrid and simply refresh the source like:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource=null;
dataGrid.ItemsSource = myCustomList;
```

Or you might do something like this:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string firstColum = firstTextBox.Text;
        string secondColum = secondTextBox.Text;
        string[] row = { firstColum, secondColum };
        yourDatagrid.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

But I'm saying again for fully correct answer you should provide / post your code.

Whatever I hope that this will help you

Comment: it doesn't work... but i listen to you and i posted my code. maybe you can check